# Find product of every digit in the given number

Tags: scala, numbers, product, digits

In scala, I need to write a method to find product of every digit in the given number. I have the following snippet.

```
  def productDigits(number: Int): Int = {
    def helper(current: Int, accumulator: Int): Int = {
      current match {
        case current if current < 10 => accumulator * current
        case _ => helper(current / 10, accumulator * (current % 10))
      }
    }
    helper(number, 1)
  }
```

Is there a better way to do?

Comment: `number.toString.map(_.toInt),product` If you want a one-liner or if your original number was read as a string in the first place. But, yours was probably more efficient _(if you already have an **Int**)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez There seems to be a bug in the one-liner, it should be `asDigit` instead of `toInt` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is jmh benchmark of OP's recursive solution vs Luis' one-liner.

Executing

`sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 10 -f 2 -t 1 bench.So59652263"`

where

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class So59652263 {
  def _dexter2305(number: Int): Int = {
    def helper(current: Int, accumulator: Int): Int = {
      current match {
        case current if current < 10 => accumulator * current
        case _ => helper(current / 10, accumulator * (current % 10))
      }
    }
    helper(number, 1)
  }

  def _luis(number: Int): Int = number.toString.map(_.asDigit).product

  val num: Int = (math.random * 100000000).toInt
  @Benchmark def dexter2305: Int = _dexter2305(num)
  @Benchmark def luis: Int = _luis(num)
}
```

gives

```
[info] So59652263.dexter2305  thrpt   20  89093066.408 ± 1825286.801  ops/s
[info] So59652263.luis        thrpt   20  11585098.230 ±  272966.526  ops/s
```

where we see recursive solution seems to have 7x more throughput than the one-liner.

---

Benchmarking when `number` is `String` instead of `Int`

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class So59652263 {
  def _dexter2305(number: String): Int = {
    def helper(current: Int, accumulator: Int): Int = {
      current match {
        case current if current < 10 => accumulator * current
        case _ => helper(current / 10, accumulator * (current % 10))
      }
    }
    helper(number.toInt, 1)
  }

  def _luis(number: String): Int = number.map(_.asDigit).product

  val num: String = (math.random * 100000000).toInt.toString
  @Benchmark def dexter2305: Int = _dexter2305(num)
  @Benchmark def luis: Int = _luis(num)
}
```

gives

```
[info] Benchmark               Mode  Cnt         Score         Error  Units
[info] So59652263.dexter2305  thrpt   20  36237007.844 ± 1631349.975  ops/s
[info] So59652263.luis        thrpt   20  13975984.042 ± 1890083.941  ops/s
```

where we see recursive solution still has higher throughput, however, by a smaller factor of 2.5 than when `number` was `Int`.

Comment: It may be worth testing what would be the performance if `number` would be a **String** instead of an **Int**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Do you mean like so https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FZu78b9BQSCZlgqXj0FS4Q

Comment: Yes, exactly like that - I was sure my implementation was slower if it was already an **Int**, but not sure if it was already an **String**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Recursive still ahead, however, by a smaller factor of 2.5.

Comment: Wow, amazing. And in that case, I guess one could even make it even faster by just iterating the **String** char by char.